# IME Consecutive Input code for Samsung TV

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I need to create login panel in Samsung TV app. In UX guide, I can see that Consecutive Input can solve my problem.

This is where UX guide I referred.
 http://www.samsungdforum.com/UxGuide/2014/05_text_input.html#ux-05

This is my current code

```
    <form name="xxx" id="xxx">
    <label for="username">Username : </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength="15" required />
    <label for="password">Password : </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="10"   required />
    <input type="button" id="uvSubmit" value="Enter" name="submit" />
  </form>

   // JS
    var imeBox = new IMEShell_Common(); 
    document.getElementById('username').focus();
    imeBox.onShow();
```

Have anyone done this before.?

Hope you can assist me to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Even though consecutive input is introduced in UX guide, there is no API for consecutive input.

but you can make code similar to consecutive input.

http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00006/Common_popup_IME.html

by imeBox.onCompleteFunc, make focus consecutive

ex:

```
function onCompleteText(arg){

    if(imeBox.inputboxID == 'username'){

        document.getElementById('password').focus(); 

        imeBox.onShow();

    }

}


imeBox.onCompleteFunc = onCompleteText;
```